# What does MAX aggregation on an entity identification variable do?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to migrate old code that uses JPA 1.0 and Hibernate 3.3 (yes, it's *really* old) to a different (non-SQL) data API. One of the queries looks something like this:

```
SELECT tx.transactionId, MAX(tx), SUM(tx.amount)
  FROM Transaction tx
  WHERE tx.customerId = :customerId
  AND ... // etc
  GROUP BY tx.transactionId
```

My question: **What should the result of `MAX(tx)` be?** All of the documentation I've seen claims that `MAX` is only valid for comparable scalar values (numbers, strings, dates), not entity references. From context, the query in fact returns instances of `Transaction`, but I can't tell what those instance are (specific persisted entities? composite entities of some kind?) or how they relate to the grouped result sets.

Is this some Hibernate extension to the spec? I couldn't find anything in the Hibernate docs either, and I wasn't able to locate the code in the Hibernate sources that deals with that specific behavior. I actually don't care either way (since I have to rewrite the entire call in a different manner anyway), I just would like to know what the replacement should do.

Anybody recognize this?